# Django-views.py: How to perform the inner join

Tags: python, django, join, django-models

I have the two following models:

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    locker_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    locker_name = models.CharField(db_column='Locker_name', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    city = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    locker_capacity = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
```

and:

```
class Table2(models.Model):
    key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    locker = models.ForeignKey(Table1)
    empty_slots = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now using django and python I want to make the following query and return a new tuple structure. The SQL analogy is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
INNER Table2
ON Table1.locker_id=Table2.locker_id;
```

Can anyone help me out with the syntax, or any reference. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`QuerySet.select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
Table2.objects.all().select_related('locker')
```

to get tuple structures, use [`QuerySet.values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list):

```
Table2.objects.all().select_related('locker') \
      .values_list('locker__locker_id', 'locker__locker_name',
                   'locker__city', 'locker__state', 'locker__pincode',
                   'locker__locker_capacity', 'key', 'empty_slots')

# If you don't specify fields, you will get fields of Table2 only.
```

Comment: any clue on how to print it template. How do we print such a format in results.html

Comment: @Anonymous, I don't get what you mean.

Comment: How do we display and iterate over the final objects so obtained in a template. I want to display the object list, in a tabular form. Now when I use the following code: Nothing is being displayed:Please note that qlist is the resulting list so found using the above answer.
{% for ob in qlist %}

         <td>{{ob.empty_slots_prime}}</td>
         <td>{{ob.city}}</td>

Comment: @Anonymous, You may need to use `values` instead of `values_list`. Then in template: `{% for ob in qlist %}<tr><td>{{ ob.empty_slots }}</td><td>{{ ob.locker_city }}</td></tr>{% endif %}`   (replaced `empty_slots_prime` with `empty_slots`, and `city` with `locker__city` to match the code in the answer)